# await task completion in a thread ends (breaks) this thread in C# .net6

Tags: c#, async-await

have a problem when using await in a thread function.
It seems that await breaks the thread. Below the test class to demonstrate this.

```
    public class Question {
    public static async Task<double> testTask() {
        // [2]
        await Task.Run(() => {
            Console.WriteLine("start testTask {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                Task.Delay(10).Wait();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("end testTask {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });

        return 42.00;

    }

    static async Task ThreadFunction() {
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadFunction begin tid={0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        // [1]
        //double x = await test.testTask().ConfigureAwait(true);
        double x = await test.testTask();


        int inserted = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

        // [3]
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadFunction end tid={0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }


    public static void startTestThread() {

        Console.WriteLine("start startTestThread. tid={0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread TestThread = new Thread(() => ThreadFunction());
        TestThread.Start();
        TestThread.Join();
        // [4]
        Console.WriteLine("end startTestThread. tid={0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

**startTestThread()** is called from outside, a console application
in the new manner without a main function.

When program reaches
**double x = await test.testTask();**
Thread "ThreadFunction" returns.
Rhis is what i do not understand.
The thread should wait for function
**testTask()**
to get completed.  The function is called and Task started
but the thread gets interrupted.
So the program execution sequence is not:
[1] [2] [3] [4]
instead it is:
[1] [2] [4]

, **so code at [3] not executed**.  Why is this so? Many thanks to the community

Comment: Does that code even compile?

Comment: _Do not_ `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);` in async code. Use `await Task.Delay` if at all.

Comment: `Task.Delay(10).Wait();` ... => `await Task.Delay(10);`

Comment: And do not mix Thread and Task. This makes no sense at all. Are you trying to do "async over sync" ?

Comment: _"without a main function."_ - And that's what you get from _that_, Microsoft. It of course _does_ have a Main function. You just don't see it.

Comment: _" The thread should wait for function testTask() to get completed."_ - exactly _not_. The thread is (potentially) freed to do other stuff. As soon as the operation that is represented by the Task returned is complete, a (possibly different) Thread will be able to pick up from there.

Comment: @Paulo The code compiles.

Comment: The System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) is just to simulate some work.  The thread needs to proceed during an async DB operation is performed. So the async task raised from within the thread is required. Or is this against the .NET async design? Thank you for comments.

Comment: The thread should wait for function testTask() to get completed." - exactly not...This could may be the problem. You mean because the excecution after await contniues in the thread where the taks been executed, the calling thread (if not main) is terminated? But the task just started and not been completed.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `async` and `await` in various places.

Furthermore, using `Thread.Start` to run a `Task` is wrong on so many levels:  the thread will finish as soon as you hit the first `await`. Instead, if you want to run it synchronously, use `Task.Run` and `Wait`, but note that you may get a deadlock if you have a `SynchronizationContext` set up (not usually the case in a console app).

Ideally you shouldn't do sync-over-async ever. Take a read of [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/) and [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) article for may reasons why this is a bad idea.

```cs
public class Question
{
    public static async Task<double> testTask()
    {
        // [2]
        await Task.Run(async () => {   // async HERE!!
            Console.WriteLine("start testTask {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                await Task.Delay(10);     // await HERE!!
            }
            Console.WriteLine("end testTask {0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        });

        return 42.00;
    }

    static async Task ThreadFunction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadFunction begin tid={0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        // [1]
        //double x = await test.testTask().ConfigureAwait(true);
        double x = await test.testTask();

        int inserted = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            await Task.Delay(100);  // await HERE!!

        // [3]
        Console.WriteLine("ThreadFunction end tid={0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    public static void startTestThread() {

        Console.WriteLine("start startTestThread. tid={0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Task.Run(ThreadFunction).Wait();
        // [4]
        Console.WriteLine("end startTestThread. tid={0}", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

I have no idea what you are trying to test with `ManagedThreadId` but it's unlikely to be useful. If using tasks with `await` then you **shouldn't care** which thread you are on, the synchronization context will sort that out. And if you were using threads then of course you remain on the same thread, you are still in the same function call.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Will check. The purpose of ThreadFunction is a thread rather than a task. Within the thread, i need some async ops (DB inserts), without the thread to break its work. Is this is not inline with the design of threads and task in .NET 6?

Comment: No that's not what threads do. Think of it this way: threads are workers, and tasks are work to be done. If you only give a thread a single task, then as soon as that task hits an `await` it's going to drop it and end the thread. That's what the threadpool is for, to offload tasks to a pool of threads that continually loop and pick up tasks to do. Why do you feel you need to mix these two conocepts, why do you feel you even need to touch threads at all? Why is threading relevant to what you are doing, which is fundamentally an async operation, and is perfectly placed to utilize the threadpool?